# CKQuery for array containing any from array (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

I would like to create a CKQueryOperation that finds records where an array contains any items from another array. It does not need to contain all of the elements from the second array, just at least one.

I have this line which works for an array containing a string but I can not seem to find what I am looking for.

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "keywords CONTAINS 'myWord'")
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orderNumber", ascending: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Records", predicate: pred)
```

Thank you

Comment: What type is the `keywords` field?

Comment: A String Array.

Comment: Not sure it will work but maybe something like: `NSPredicate(format: "ANY keywords IN %@", someList)`.

Comment: Okay I'll take a look at that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. `let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY your_array == %@", predicateObject)` - find one object in your array.
2. `let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY your_array IN %@", [predicateObject])` - find any object in your array.